# Css cursor pointer doesn't work in html select on ie7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to set cursor as pointer for html select on ie7 but it doesn't work, is there a way to fix it?

```
<select style="cursor:pointer;">
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry, yes this does happen in IE7.

Comment: Fairly certain in IE7 they don't let you style much of the select box.  The only thing I would try is applying your `style="cursor: pointer"` to the parent element.  The other option is to mimic the functionality of a `<select>` through `<div>`s and the like and get it to work that way (similar to the way jquery ui components function).  That way you can have the functional select but the freedom to style it.

Answer (score 2):

IE7 **does** support the `cursor:pointer` style.  -- see http://quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html. The only browsers that don't support it are IE5.5 and earlier, but you can safely ignore them these days.

So if it isn't working for you in this specific case, it's not IE7 in general that's at fault, so I'd suspect the `<select>` tag has a lot to do with it.

When IE renders a `<select>` element, it actually behind the scenes uses an ActiveX control to display the operating system's drop-down selector widget. This is different to how it handles other field types, which are rendered directly by the browser rendering engine.

This difference is usually transparent to the user, but does show up occasionally with the odd glitch.

The most common glitch is that `<select>` boxes ignore `z-index`, and always show on top in IE, making them harder to work with if you want to do clever stuff like toggle between a select box and an input field. Work arounds for this glitch usually involve an iFrame.

My guess would be that problems setting the cursor type on a select box are another glitch from this same underlying cause.

If this is the case, then I have my doubts that you're going to be able to do anything about it. You might just have to live with older versions of IE not being able to set the cursor for these fields.

Comment: IMO, this isn't an answer. You haven't said how this could be fixed.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - I said "I have my doubts that you're going to be able to do anything about it". My opinion is that there isn't a solution; I don't think it can be fixed. This is an answer to the question. It may not be the one that the OP was hoping for, but it is an answer.